# how to add pagination to this

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I'm trying to add pagination to my search results I get on my view page. I'm pretty much confused with getting url like..

```
localhost:81/profile/index.php/main/search?query=vi
```

What i'm trying to get is:

```
localhost:81/profile/index.php/main/search?query=vi&off=5
```

with the offset value, when clicked on 1,2,3 pagination links.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller{

function index()
{     


    $this->load->view('main_view');

}

function search()
{

    $off = $_GET['off'];

    $query = $_GET['query'];

    $min_length = 1;



    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length)
    {
        $query_str = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerName LIKE '%$query%' LIMIT 10 OFFSET '$off'";
        echo $query_str;
        $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerName LIKE '%$query%' LIMIT 10 OFFSET $off")->result_array();

        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
        echo "<tr><th>Number</th><th>Name</th><th>address</th><th>phone</th></tr>";

        foreach($result as $data)
            {
                echo "<tr></tr>";       
                echo "<td>".$data['customerNumber']."</td>"."<td>".$data['customerName']."</td>"."<td>".$data['addressLine1']."</td>".
                "<td>".$data["phone"]."</td>";

            }


    }
    else
    { 
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }

    $this->load->view('main_view');
}}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[If only CodeIgniter had a great user guide, and a pagination library.](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html)

Take a look at the above page. You then want to filter your records when selecting them based on the parameters in the URL.

Comment: how do they do it in simple php way, like creating links 1,2,3,4 on view page and when clicked on, it changes the offset value to 5,10,15.
is it possible?

Comment: Thanks, i figured it out. 
all i had to do was use $_get to get the $off when view.
I will start using codeigniter way.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: this is my view: 
<form action="main/search" class="search-form noframe inbtn rlarge lblue" method="GET">
 <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $off=0; ?>"/>
    <input type="text" name="query" class="search-input" placeholder="Search..." value=""/>
    <input class="search-btn" type="submit" value="Go" />
 </form>
now, whenever i click on go after entering value, 
sometimes it goes to http://localhost:81/profile/index.php/main/main/search?query=a
instead of http://localhost:81/profile/index.php/main/search?query=a
how to get around this?

Comment: It’s because the URL in the form action attribute is relative. Try using the built-in URL helper (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) instead of hard-coding your URLs. Honestly, use the user guide.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Fixed. i echoed base url, its working fine now.
Thats a lot of help. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it sorted.