# Undefined Variable error in View

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, view

My controller is in  this question:
[how to add pagination to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584783/how-to-add-pagination-to-this)

But now, i'm getting undefined variable in my view,
View has an input

```
<input name='query'/>
```

which i receive it in controller as,

```
$query = $this->input->get('query');
```

Now, i am trying to pass the same query string back into my view
inside the link of pagination.

```
<a href="<php echo base_url(); ?>main/search/query=<?php echo $query; ?>&off=<?php echo $off=5;">1</a>
```

`$off` works but not `$query`. But i'm NOT saving the `$query` to the database.
so, i cant use `$data['query']` as well. totally confused.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I edited your code formatting a bit. Indent 4 spaces for code blocks to get syntax highlighting.  You can enclose small inline bits like the variables `$query` in backquotes, but they won't be highlighted.  Also you can select/highlight blocks and ctl-k to format the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped. i was looking for the buttons for formatting which i couldn't find. I will follow the rules from next time i ask a question.

Comment: no rule broken :) Just have to learn the system.  There is a button in the editor, it looks like `{ }` - I don't think I have _ever_ used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$off is not throwing an error because you are assigning the integer 5 to it.

You need to pass data to the view from inside the controller  by sticking it in an array like

```
 $data['query']= $query;
 $this->load->view('myview', $data);
```

Then $query is available to the view.  Not sure why you say you can't do this

Comment: Fantastic, so, i add this $query= $_GET['query'] and it started working. That was very quick. Thanks.
Is this the correct way to it?
<a href="<php echo base_url(); ?>main/search/query=<?php echo $query=$_GET['query']; ?>&off=<?php echo $off=5;">1</a>
It works though.

Comment: @Mirage no, pass it to the view from the controller

Comment: yup, passed and that worked too. Why is not the right way to do $_GET['query'] inside view itself when it actually worked. Any future problems when the code gets bigger or something? Just asking.

Comment: @Mirage passing the variables to the view using the array menthod that ray has suggested is best one.a) its more readable and easy to send data from controller to view b) using href is the wrong way to load a view in codeigniter c) if u use href , the data will be visible to front end user which might be security threat