# Undefined variable: error in adding field into db

Tags: php

I'm getting `error:Undefined variable: error` 
in my code:

```
            public function add(){
    $this->polls_model->rules = Pf::event()->trigger("filter","polls-adding-validation-rule",$this->polls_model->rules);

    $template = null;
    $template = Pf::event()->trigger("filter","polls-add-template",$template);
    if ($this->request->is_post()){
        $data = array();
        $data["polls_question"] = $this->post->{"polls_question"};
        $data["polls_pubdate"] = str_to_mysqldate($this->post->{"polls_pubdate"},$this->polls_model->elements_value["polls_pubdate"],"Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $data["polls_unpubdate"] = str_to_mysqldate($this->post->{"polls_unpubdate"},$this->polls_model->elements_value["polls_unpubdate"],"Y-m-d H:i:s");
        if (is_array($this->post->{"polls_status"})){
            $data["polls_status"] = implode(",",$this->post->{"polls_status"});
        }else{
            $data["polls_status"] = $this->post->{"polls_status"};
        }
        $port_answer = isset($this->post->{"answer"}) ? $this->post->{"answer"} : array();
        $data = Pf::event()->trigger("filter","polls-post-data",$data);
        $data = Pf::event()->trigger("filter","polls-adding-post-data",$data);
        $var = array();
        $pollq_multiple_yes = intval($this->post->{'pollq_multiple_yes'});
        $data['polls_multiple'] = 0;
        if ($pollq_multiple_yes == 1) {
            if(intval($this->post->{'pollq_multiple'}) > count($port_answer)){
                $data['polls_multiple'] = 1;
            }else{
                $data['polls_multiple'] = intval($this->post->{'pollq_multiple'});
            }
        } else {
            $data['polls_multiple'] = 1;
        }
        //debug($data);
        Pf::database()->query('START TRANSACTION');
        $inserted = $this->polls_model->insert($data);
        if($inserted === false){
            Pf::database()->query('ROLLBACK');
        }else{
            $new_id = $this->polls_model->insert_id();
            $insert_meta = true;
            if(count($port_answer) > 0){
                $custom = array();
                $int = count($port_answer);
                for ($i = 0; $i < $int ; $i++) {
                    if(!empty($port_answer[$i])){
                        $custom = array(
                                'pollsa_qid' => $new_id,
                                'pollsa_answers' => e($port_answer[$i]),
                        );
                    }
                    $insert_meta = $this->answers_model->insert($custom);
                }
                if($insert_meta === false){
                    Pf::database()->query('ROLLBACK');

                }else{
                    Pf::database()->query('COMMIT');
                }
            }
            Pf::database()->query('COMMIT');
        }
        $errors = Pf::validator()->get_readable_errors(false);
        foreach ($errors as $key => $value) {
            $error[$key][0] = $errors[$key][0];
        }

        $this->view->errors =  $error; // error here!
        $var['content'] = $this->view->fetch($template);
        if (count($error) > 0){// and here!!!
            $var['error'] = 1;
        }else{
            Pf::event()->trigger("action","polls-add-successfully",$this->polls_model->insert_id(),$data);
            $var['error'] = 0;
            $var['url'] = admin_url($this->action.'=index&ajax=&id=&token=');
        }

        echo json_encode($var);
    }else{

        $this->view->render($template);
    }
}
```

I edited code, added function code.

This is my add function, if I want add poll with answers.

It gives me this error to my log.

I found this tutorial [Undefined Variable error in View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597031/undefined-variable-error-in-view)

I've googled it but didnt find anything special what helps me out.

Comment: You are working with `$error` variable, that doenst exist. You should define it first.

Comment: @insider I've updated my post. I have variable.

Comment: even after edit, you are still missing definition of `$error` variable. As the error is under the foreach, i would say the `$errors` variable is empty so the foreach gets skipped. Otherwise you would get the same error inside of the foreach loop.

Comment: `$error` variable does not exist, that's what it's telling you.  You never defined it anywhere

Comment: It looks like you're trying to accumulate some kind of validation errors into a new array?  There are some problems with this code.  I would initialize a new array first, and then think about what you want to 'push' into that array during your iteration of `$errors`.

Comment: $error = array();
$error[$key][0] = $errors[$key][0];
   the right way is below
    $error[$key] = $errors[$key];
 i actually dont know what you want to do but this is the right way         
 but providing [0] will make it some how constant.

Answer (score 0):

Initiate the variable as an array.
   because if the $error is empty the compiler will see it as an array.
  if not it will get an error.

```
    $error = [];

    $errors = Pf::validator()->get_readable_errors(false);
                 foreach ($errors as $key => $value) {
                   //  $error[$key][0] = $errors[$key][0];
                   // the right way is below
                   // i actually dont know what you want to do but this is the right way         
                   // but providing [0] will make it some how constant.
                   $error[$key] = $errors[$key]
                 }
                $this->view->errors =  $error; // error showing here!
                $var['content'] = $this->view->fetch($template);
                if (count($error) > 0){ // and here???
                    $var['error'] = 1;
                }else{
                    Pf::event()->trigger("action","polls-add-successfully",$this->polls_model->insert_id(),$data);
                    $var['error'] = 0;
                    $var['url'] = admin_url($this->action.'=index&ajax=&id=&token=');
                }
```

Comment: It looks like 2D array inside of the loop so 1D array may throw another errors.

Comment: @insider it doent matter whether is 2D array or ? atleast it will give him some insight

Comment: My bad, didnt expect PHP to be that "smart" and to handle 2 indecies for array as 2D array even though it is defined as 1D. Basicly index on null creates an array in PHP :O

Comment: @insider can you please look at the foreach  loop and watch it well. You will see it obvious 1D array is want he want . If not it will provide some constant index for 2D tht u are talking about.

Comment: It is ok, I was just confused with `$new_array['new_index'][0] = 123` to be valid syntax for PHP as `$new_array['new_index']` is null / undefined offset. PHP just decided the empty value will become an array and then it assigned value (works on PHP 7.0.8)